# How to disable the cache access of Berkeley db?

Tags: c, database, berkeley-db

Recently I'm carrying out an time cost experiment in which Berkeley DB program needs to read data from disk db and process them. I want the Berkely DB to merely read using IO to disk. However, after processing for some time, it will begin to read from cache as cache has stored some pages loaded in the past. I don't want this happen. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: The only thing that springs to mind is using the O_DIRECT flag, but I don't think it will work as it requires reads and writes to be sector aligned. Besides, using the cache is a good thing, isn't it?

Comment: @Ian Abbott. Of course cache is a good thing. But I just want to show a situation where IO is the bottleneck of efficiency improvement. If all the data are read from cache, It will be impossible for me to show it since reading cost will be not so different from other parts of program.